# Can we use axios post inside axios post?

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, nativescript-vue

I need to get session id from the api and use that as a part of my input for Axios POST to get user information. However, I am always getting session expired error although I cannot find any mistakes in my code. Help me out please!

```
   data() {
        return {
            customer: {
                data:{
                    method: "customer_login",
                    email: "vishal@magemad.com",
                    password: "admin123",
                    session_id: ""
                }
            }
        };
```

---

login() {

```
            var api = 'http://159.203.179.154/sports-web/webservices/api2.php';
            var admin = {
                    data: {
                        method: "admin_login",
                        key: "admin123",
                        user: "admin"  
                    }                  
            };
            let  axiosConfig = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    }
            }; 

            Axios.post(api, admin, axiosConfig)
                .then((res) => {
                    const id = res.data.data.session_id.slice(2,-2);
                    this.customer.data.session_id = id;

                    Axios.post(api, this.customer)
                        .then((res) => {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.customer.data));
                            //console.log(res);
                            alert(JSON.stringify(res));
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log("AXIOS ERROR:", err);
                        });
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(this.customer));
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("AXIOS ERROR:", err);
                });
```

Comment: I don't know how your backend works but with this you are trying to login as customer after you logged in as admin. There is no problem in frontend code but you are probably doing something that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It turned out that I did not need to slice the session id.